# Is the positive fragment of second-order logic compact?

Tags: lo.logic

This is a crosspost of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4486438) that I posted on the math stack exchange a year and a half ago.

---

There are two slightly different versions of compactness in the FOL setting:

1. If $\Delta$ is finitely satisfiable, then $\Delta$ is satisfiable.
2. If $\Gamma \models \varphi$ then there exists a finite subset $\Gamma_0 \subset \Gamma$ such that $\Gamma_0 \models \varphi$.

I'm interested in the second one here because positive second-order logic does not have actual contradictions. For second-order logic though, these two notions line up.

Consider second-order logic with a single non-empty domain. We have function and relation symbols as vocabulary items. A constant is a nullary function.

Additionally, quantifiers can introduce functions and relations of arbitrary arity (e.g. $\exists f / 2$ or $\forall R / 3$). Suppose our connectives are $\land$, $\lor$ and $\lnot$.

Consider the fragment without $\lnot$. Let's call this positive second-order logic.

Positive second-order logic with Henkin semantics is definitely compact.

**I'm wondering whether positive second-order logic with full semantics is compact.**

Comment: Colin McQuillen posted an answer over on stack exchange.